# How to make custom navigation bar for the app in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing app in swiftUI in which every screen has same custom navigation bar with diff titles.

Instead of creating custom navigation view in every screen I want to reuse it.

What will be the best approach to do that?

for now i have done as follow but this works only for single screen

```
var body: some View {
      ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image("Custom_Navigation_Image")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(height: 135)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Spacer()
            }
       }
```

I want to create custom navigation as below
[image]

Thank You for help

Comment: I interpret your question as "How do I communicate changes in a child view to the parent view?". There are 2 basic ways: passing Bindings (as parameters or as Environment variables) and, perhaps more elegantly, through Preferences. Here's a good guide on the second one: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/15/the-magic-of-view-preferences-in-swiftui/

Comment: Oh, and there is a disgraceful way – making a "singleton" shared ObservableObject and keeping your navigation state in it, but let this remain between us or we both will be expelled from the Programmers' Guild.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom view wherein Navigation View embeds the current view:

```
struct CustomNavBar<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    let title: String
    let content: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Image("12345")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(height: 135)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    Spacer()
                }
                content
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var body: some View {

    CustomNavBar(title: "Custom Nav", content:
               Text("Testing")
    )
```